# Website translations in [Odoo 15] change links and images

Tags: python, html, odoo

I've found a way to change links, images, and links in Odoo's translations

But I have a question, is this method effective? and will it affect the performance of the website due to the repetition of the code?

[link code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuSlU.png)

@george

```
<t name="Homepage" t-name="website.homepage1">
    <t t-call="website.layout">
        <t t-set="pageName" t-value="'homepage'"/>
        <t t-if="'en' in request.env.lang">
            <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty">
                <section class="s_text_image pt32 pb32 o_colored_level" data-snippet="s_image_text" data-name="Image - Text" style="background-image: none;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 pt16 pb16 o_colored_level">
                                <img src="/web/image/website.s_image_text_default_image" class="img img-fluid mx-auto" alt="" loading="lazy"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 pt16 pb16 o_colored_level">
                                <h2 class="o_default_snippet_text">Section Subtitle</h2>
                                <p class="o_default_snippet_text">Write one or two paragraphs describing your product or services. To be successful your content needs to be useful to your readers.</p>
                                <p class="o_default_snippet_text">Start with the customer – find out what they want and give it to them.</p>
                                <p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 o_default_snippet_text">Discover more</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </t>
                        <t t-if="'ar' in request.env.lang">
            <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty">
                <section class="s_text_image pt32 pb32 o_colored_level" data-snippet="s_image_text" data-name="Image - Text" style="background-image: none;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 pt16 pb16 o_colored_level">
                                <img src="/web/image/4480-5237e045/pngtree-arabic-ramadan-kareem-calligraphy-ramadhan-greeting-text-lettering-sticker-ramazan-mubarak-png-image_6591593-150x150.png?" class="img img-fluid mx-auto" alt="" loading="lazy"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 pt16 pb16 o_colored_level">
                                <h2 class="o_default_snippet_text">Section Subtitle1</h2>
                                <p class="o_default_snippet_text">Write one or two paragraphs describing your product or services. To be successful your content needs to be useful to your readers.</p>
                                <p class="o_default_snippet_text">Start with the customer – find out what they want and give it to them.</p>
                                <p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 o_default_snippet_text">Discover more</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </t>

    </t>
</t>
```

Comment: any answer......